# Java Spring Boot - Connect dynamic multiple Database

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm confused about how to connect Spring  dynamically to multiple databases, depending on the request?
For Example : 
1. In admin site, register new member. 
2. Database admin creates a new database for this new member.
3. Spring boot .jar, when in run mode, just adds some configuration lines  to the external file, this service can connect to the new added database.

member 1 has url 1 => www.example.com/member-1 connect to db_member_1
member 2 has url 2 => www.example.com/member-2 connect to db_member_2
... etc

So I mean, I don't need to update my source code, but just add some lines in my external configuration file,so this spring boot .jar can connect to the new database.
I have tried connect two databases in 1 spring boot but I don't know how to make it dynamically without unloading my spring boot.
I use JPA to connect my master database and use JdbcTemplate to connect my transaction database.

Thanks in advance. :)

Regards,

Peter Susanto

Comment: Hi, Peter Susanto, i guess you need a dynamic datasource routing , here is a post about it : https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing and an example of spring-boot + AbstractRoutingDataSource : https://github.com/lenicliu/eg-spring/tree/master/eg-spring-boot/eg-spring-boot-routingdatasource